# join a many to many table using multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, many-to-many

I'm using sqlite3 and trying to select all the articles that have any of (or all of) the given tags.

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (title)
);
CREATE TABLE tag (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (name)
);
CREATE TABLE drill_to_tag (
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    article_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, article_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tag (id),
    FOREIGN KEY(article_id) REFERENCES article (id)
);
```

Let's say tag id 4 is "news", tag id 5 is "europe", and tag id 6 is "usa".

I can get articles with tag id 4 using:

```
select a.title from article a
  inner join article_to_tag
    on a.id = article_to_tag.article_id
    where article_to_tag.tag_id = 4;
```

But what I really want is a way to get articles appear in the many-to-many table with *both* tags 4 and 5 -- europe news.

This query does that but it seems ugly?

```
select a.id, a.title from article a
  inner join article_to_tag atag1
    on a.id = atag1.article_id
  inner join article_to_tag atag2
    on a.id = atag2.article_id
  where atag1.tag_id = 4 and atag2.tag_id = 5;
```

And this one seems even uglier.

```
select a.id, a.title from article a
  where
    a.id in (select article_id from article_to_tag where article_id = 4)
      and
    a.id in (select article_id from article_to_tag where article_id = 5);
```

Is there a better type of join or some other way to form this query?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts are just fine (few typos left aside): you can use multiple `join`s, or `in` conditions with subqueries.

One other method, which is pretty close to the `in` technique, uses an `exists` condition for each tag id:

```
select a.*
from article a
where 
    exists (
        select 1 from article_to_tag at where at.article_id = a.article_id and at.tag_id = 4
    ) and exists (
        select 1 from article_to_tag at where at.article_id = a.article_id and at.tag_id = 5
    )
```

For all these queries (`join`s, `in`, `exists`), you do want an index on `article_to_tag(article_id, tag_id)`.

A more concise way is to use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select a.id, a.title
from article a
inner join article_tag at on at.article_id = a.article_id
where at.tag_id in (4, 5)
group by a.id, a.title
having count(ditinct at.tag_id) = 2
```

This is easier to modify to take in account more tags, however you would need to assess the performance of this solution against your real data; aggregation tend to slow down on large datasts.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by a.title` and set a condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select a.title 
from article a inner join article_to_tag t
on a.id = t.article_id
where t.tag_id in (4, 5)
group by a.title
having count(distinct t.tag_id) = 2
```

This solution is scalable because you can query for as many tags as you want in the `IN` clause and change just their number in the `HAVING` clause.